# Assigning a regex pattern match to a variable in perl

Tags: regex, perl, variables

I want to match a regex pattern and assign the matched pattern to a variable.

I then want to print the value assigned to the variable.

---

My attempt

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $variable = 'iaw75w8yu';
my $value =~ /w[0-9][0-9]w[0-9]/;
print $value;
```

---

Desired output

```
w75w8
```

---

Actual output

```
Use of uninitialized value $value in pattern match (m//) at ./temp.pl line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $value in print at ./temp.pl line 6.
```

Comment: `$value` is uninitialized and you never use `$variable`. I think you have typo.

Comment: Please read docs, starting with say [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).  The `$var =~ /$patt/` attemtps to match `$patt` in `$var`.  If you use capturing parens `$var =~ /($patt)/` then the match, if found, is in `$1`.  Or assign as: `my ($match) = $var =~ /other($patt)stuff/;`, if it's one match.You still need `()` to supply _list context_ to the match operator, so that it does return the actual match and not just the number. Also,  without parens in regex, `($patt)`, the whole thing is returned (if matched). Please read docs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I usually do it like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

# the variable
my $variable = 'iaw75w8yu';

# the value
my $value;

# regex for the variable
if ( $variable =~ /(w[0-9][0-9]\w[0-9])/ ) {
    $value = $1;
}
else {
    $value = "regex not found";
}
print $value;
```

Answer (score 3):

This works too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $variable = 'iaw75w8yu';

my $value = $1 if ($variable =~ /(w[0-9][0-9]\w[0-9])/);

print $value if defined ($value);
```

It seems closer to what you initialy intended to try. But the shortfall of this method is that it could happen that your value doesn't get defined. It's something important to keep in mind when you start having optional captures in a m// statement.

Answer (score 1):

> This should be printing `w78w8`

No, it shouldn't! Even if your code was correct, it would *never* print `w78w8` because the source string you're trying to match against doesn't contain `w78w8`. In the examples below, I'm going to assume you meant to say `w75w8`.

The problem is that you're trying to match an undefined value, the result of which is undefined. Your code is printing warnings, which is exactly what it should be printing since you specified `-w`.

If you want to capture something, you need a [capture group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

'iaw75w8yu' =~ /(w\d\dw\d)/;
print Dumper($1);
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = 'w75w8';
```

If you want to store the matches in a variable of your choosing, you need to evaluate the expression in list context:

```
my @matches = ('iaw75w8yu' =~ /(w\d\dw\d)/);
print Dumper(\@matches);
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'w75w8'
        ];
```